# Using a custom factory to create destination type with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have `CustomerDto` and `CustomerDomainModel`. I want Automapper to use the `DataBindingFactory` [mentioned here](http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged) when constructing a `CustomerDomainModel` object. I have had a look at `ConstructUsing` and `AfterMap` functions in `Mapper` class but I could not find a way of getting done what I want. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `ConstructUsing` for this.  You might have to explicitly cast to the correct expression like this though:

```
class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, CustomerDomainModel>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
                      .ConstructUsing((Func<ResolutionContext, CustomerDomainModel>) (rc => DataBindingFactory.Create<CustomerDomainModel>()));

            var dto = new CustomerDto {FirstName = "First", LastName = "Last"};
            var domain = Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, CustomerDomainModel>(dto);
            Console.WriteLine("First: " + domain.FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("Last: " + domain.LastName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class CustomerDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerDomainModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public static class DataBindingFactory
    {
        public static T Create<T>()
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
    }
```